# svcutil.exe and multiple XSD files

Tags: c#, soap, svcutil.exe

I'm new to `SOAP` and I'm trying to use `svcutil.exe` generate `C#` classes from a `.WSDL` file which references multiple `XSD` files to define the various types

My file structure is this:

```
service.wsdl
type$a.xsd
type$b.xsd
etc..
type$z.xsd
```

I've tried running the command:

```
svcutil.exe service.wsdl *.xsd  /t:code /l:c#
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error: There was an error verifying some XML Schemas generated during export:
Undefined complexType 'http://[...censored...]/bo:xmloutT' is used as a base for complex type extension.
```

The type `bo:xmloutT` is correctly defined in one of the XSD files, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used `xsd.exe` instead of `svcutil.exe`

They have a similar syntax for generating code, but xsd.exe worked correctly where the other one didn't, for some reason.